# Align enumerate/itemize in tabular with rect text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, enumerate, itemize, tikz-shape

How can I get the list to align vertically with the preceding text?  In the middle cell, I want 1. to align vertically with "Inputs." In the bottom cell, "Goals" should be in the middle vertically between 1. and 2.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{rect} = [rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3, draw]

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[rect](first) {
\textbf{Parse FCC Broadband Availability Data}
\nodepart{two}
Inputs:
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item FCC Form 477 Data
\end{enumerate}
\end{tabular}
\nodepart{three}
Goals:
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Select states and ISPs
    \item Baseline for comparison.
\end{enumerate}
\end{tabular}
};

\end{document}
```

[image: item]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))  by adding the documentclass as well as the *relevant*  packages. What exactly odes "[minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)" mean here? Do you want the box to start directly from the left margin without any indentation or something else?

Comment: @leandriis Fixed! In the middle cell, I want 1. to align vertically with "Inputs." In the bottom cell, "Goals" should be in the middle vertically between 1. and 2.

Comment: Thanks for providing the additional information. Is there a special reason for using a `tikzpicture` for this instead of a `tabular`?

Comment: Nope, I just followed another question that recommended `tabular` and a `p` column for inserting a list but did not demonstrate alignment.

Comment: EDIT: I have 4 of these tables that need to be connected with arrows horizontally. This is possibly motivation for still using a tikzpicture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `tikzpicture`, I suggest using a simple `tabular`. With the help of `cellspace` you can adjust the spacing above and below the text in the cells. I have used the `enumitem` package in order to define a customized `tabenum` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=*, nosep,leftmargin=*,before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},after=\end{minipage}}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|0l0{p{4.25cm}}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|0c|}{\bfseries Parse FCC Broadband Availability Data}\\
\hline
Inputs: & \begin{tabenum} 
            \item FCC Form 477 Data 
          \end{tabenum} \\
\hline
Goals: & \begin{tabenum}
           \item Select states and ISPs
           \item Baseline for comparison.
          \end{tabenum} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=*, nosep,leftmargin=*,before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},after=\end{minipage}}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(first) {
  \begin{tabular}{|0l0{p{4.25cm}}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|0c|}{\bfseries Parse FCC Broadband Availability Data}\\
  \hline
  Inputs: & \begin{tabenum} 
              \item FCC Form 477 Data 
            \end{tabenum} \\
  \hline
  Goals: & \begin{tabenum}
             \item Select states and ISPs
             \item Baseline for comparison.
            \end{tabenum} \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}};
\node[below=of first](second) {
  \begin{tabular}{|0l0{p{4.25cm}}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|0c|}{\bfseries Parse FCC Broadband Availability Data}\\
  \hline
  Inputs: & \begin{tabenum} 
              \item FCC Form 477 Data 
            \end{tabenum} \\
  \hline
  Goals: & \begin{tabenum}
             \item Select states and ISPs
             \item Baseline for comparison.
            \end{tabenum} \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}};
\draw [->] (first) -- (second);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was originally creating a much more complex diagram, hence using tikzpicture. I will play with this.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, I just realized I might need a tikzpicture after all. I have four of these tables that need arrows horizontally between them from left to right.

Comment: You can use the `tabular` I showed you as the contents of the `\node`. I have edited my answer to also include an example on that.

Comment: Oh super! That is perfect then. Thank you so much!

Comment: One last Q: How can I ensure the tables are the same height if the amount of text in each cell varies (but not by much)? Word wrapping is fine.

Comment: Also, what does the '0' in '0c' do?

Comment: Ensuring tables have the same height even if they include different amounts of text requres some manual adjustment. What to do exactly here depends on the exact example. The `0` in `0c` is a prefix added by the `cellspace` package (See also its package option `column=0`). With the help of it, we can add a little bit of vertical white space between the text and the `\hline`.